# How to find the Taylor series of $\frac{1}{1+x^3}$ at $0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, taylor-expansion

I can't find a way to calculate the n-th derivative of $$f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^3}$$ in order to find its Taylor series at $0$. How could one find its Taylor series?

Comment: You don't need to find any derivatives. Find the Taylor series of $\,\frac1{1+x}\,$ and then substitute $\,x^3\,$ for $\,x.$

Comment: I can give you a hint with MATLAB: 
syms x
taylor(1/(1+x^3),'ExpansionPoint',0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few different ways to consider:

1. Brute force differentiation of $\frac{1}{1+x^3}$ - not impossible (esp. if Q asks for only low terms).
2. Find the expansion of $\frac{1}{1+x}$ and substitute x^3 in (easier)
3. Notice that $\frac{1}{1+x^3}$ looks suspiciously like the form $\frac{a}{1-r}$ which is the closed form of a geometric series when r < 1. Perhaps this would give you a series representation with suitable substitution.

Answer (score 1):

The Taylor series of $\frac {1}{1+x} = 1 - x + x^2 - x^3 + \cdots$

To find the Taylor series of $\frac {1}{1+x^3}$ substitute $x^3$ for $x$ in the series above.

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward method is to look at a database of [usual Taylor expansions](http://www.h-k.fr/publications/data/adc.ps__annexes.maths.pdf) and combine them to develop the function at hand, here that would be $\frac 1{1+u}$ applied for $u=x^3$.

Nevertheless, a common method to find an a priori unknown Taylor expansion is to find an ODE verified by $f(x)$ and solve it via power series.

This is a bit overkill here, since $\frac 1{1+x}$ has a very basic and known development (listed in the compendium above), which can also be determined as a sum of a geometric series, but let assume we start from scratch.

Here is the general method, and it can be applied to many functions:

$f(x)=\dfrac 1{1+x^3}\implies f'(x)=\dfrac{-3x^2}{(1+x^3)^2}$

We could have $f'(x)=-3x^2f(x)^2$ but this is not interesting, as power series multiplication (i.e. $f(x)^2$) is not something that can be easily calculated.

Instead we prefer the form $$(1+x^3)f'(x)+3x^2f(x)=0$$

So let search for the coefficients of $f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^n$

$\begin{align}\text{ODE} 
&=(1+x^3)\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} na_nx^{n-1}+3x^2\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^n\\\\
&=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} na_nx^{n-1}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} na_nx^{n+2}+\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} 3a_nx^{n+2}\\\\ 
&=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)a_{n+1}x^n+\sum\limits_{n=3}^{\infty} (n-2)a_{n-2}x^n+\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} 3a_{n-2}x^n\\\\
&=a_1+(2a_2)x+(3a_3+3a_0)x^2+\sum\limits_{n=3}^{\infty} \Big((n+1)a_{n+1}+(n-2)a_{n-2}+3a_{n-2}\big)x^n
\end{align}$

Identifying the coefficients to the zero series gives:

$\begin{cases}a_1=0\\2a_2=0\\3a_3+3a_0=0\\(n+1)a_{n+1}+(n+1)a_{n-2}=0\end{cases}\iff\begin{cases}a_1=0\\a_2=0\\a_3=-a_0\\a_{n+1}=-a_{n-2}\end{cases}$

Since $a_0=f(0)=1\, $ we get $\, \begin{cases}a_{3n}=(-1)^n\\a_{3n+1}=0\\a_{3n+2}=0\end{cases}$

This gives the Taylor series $\dfrac{1}{1+x^3}=1-x^3+x^6-x^9+x^{12}-x^{15}+\cdots$